# Is it possible to read google maps navigation notification using Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Is there any way to read notifications using Flutter from the google maps notifications which are shown periodically as the user moves. In online, I found in native android it is done using NotificationListenerService.

Please guide me

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by reading the notification?

Comment: send it another device overbluetooth

Comment: it means, whole notification?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is any plugin for flutter which directly implements this functionality.
But you can always write platform specific (e.g. Android with Kotlin/Java) code.
https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels

That way you can parse the Notification with a NotificationListenerService like you would do in Android